# azure redis cache key value concerns

Tags: azure-redis-cache

I have a scenario where for my azure redis cache key to be unique. I'm inclined to use a value consisting of `"<tenant guid>-<user guid>-<audience uri>-<issued at unix epoc time>"`, e.g.

```
cacheId = "90ebc5d3-7129-4a12-aabb-9f6ba00e47b5-58355802-a2e4-4b4c8ce1-df979ac4e8dc-http://targetresource.com/-1454185279"
```

Any thoughts on whether or not use of an azure redis cache key of this format or length will create issues?

```
cache.StringSet(cacheId, jwt, timeSpanOfNowUntilJwtExpiresEpocTime);  
. . .   
var userIdTokenCache = cache.StringGet(cacheId);  
if (userIdTokenCache.HasValue) { . . . } else { . . . }
```

Comment: YMMV, but [this unofficial benchmarking](http://adamnengland.com/2012/11/15/redis-performance-does-key-length-matter/) shows no/minimal `write` performance degradation below 10k-character `KEY`, and little to no `read` degradation below 100-character `KEY`. So, that should be totally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented this and so far no issues surfaced so it would appear redis cache is okay with cache keys of this format and length.